# Trying to call an object fro, within a class

Tags: python, class, object, call

I have written

```
class Spillebrett:
    def __init__ (self, rader, kolonner):
        self._rader=rader
        self._kolonner=kolonner
        self._rutenett=[[]]
        generasjon=0
        generer()

    def generer(self):
        for i in range(self._rader):
          for j in range(self._kolonner):
```

But I get

```
NameError: name 'generer' is not defined
```

Its defined further down, what do I have to do?

Comment: generer is a method belonging to the class. You have to call it using : `self.generer()`

Comment: Try `self.generer()`, that's how you refer to calss methods or attributes inside the class.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan to be precise, `self.generer` is a bound method of object `self` and not identical (as in `is not`) to `Spillebrett.generer`.

Comment: @timgeb It would be great if you could explain this to OP in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please change `generer()` to  `self.generer()`

why ? because that method belongs to the class.